# Android MediaPlayer pause() stops the player and start again

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player

I need to play audio in an Android application so I used MediaPlayer.
I created 2 buttons: Play and Pause but after I paused a song and want to resume it, the song starts again instead of resuming from where I left.

I wrote this code:

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


public void playPre(View view) {
    //mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music);
    mediaPlayer.start(); 
    ImageView pausaOneButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PausaOneButton);
    pausaOneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}

public void stopPre(View view) {

    mediaPlayer.pause();
    ImageView pausaOneButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PausaOneButton);
    pausaOneButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the MediaPlayer upon every call of `playPre()`. You could change your code to this:

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

public void playPre(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music);
    }
    mediaPlayer.start(); 
    ImageView pausaOneButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PausaOneButton);
    pausaOneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}

public void stopPre(View view) {

    mediaPlayer.pause();
    ImageView pausaOneButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PausaOneButton);
    pausaOneButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relays in `playPre(View view)`, try this:

```
if(mediaPlayer == null) {
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fire);
}
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
  return;
}
mediaPlayer .start();
```

You will also have to check **if the media is already playing** with `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()`

Here is in an example project I made for media player: 
**[Test Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sby3lfsnngmzlb1/MediaPlayerTest.zip?dl=0&fb=1&fb_action_ids=747644802020828&fb_action_types=dropboxdropbox%3Aadd)**